# Not able to give date value to the date picker in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using angular 4 with protractor 5.2.2 and cucumber 3.2.0
my HTML code is given below

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class="row">
                        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="col-md-6">
                            <label _ngcontent-c2="" class="form-control-label frx-label" for="normal-field" id="lblDOB">
                                DOB </label>
                            <span _ngcontent-c2="">
                                <b _ngcontent-c2="">:</b>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="col-md-6">
                            <ng-datepicker _ngcontent-c2="" class="frx-ng2-date-picker ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" _nghost-c3="" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="Fri Jan 12 2018 12:09:37 GMT+0"><div _ngcontent-c3="" class="ngx-datepicker-container"> <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><input _ngcontent-c3="" class="ngx-datepicker-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" readonly="readonly" type="text" ng-reflect-model="01-12-2018">  <!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--> </div> </ng-datepicker>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

i am not able to give a date value by using

```
element(by.css(".ngx-datepicker-container input")).sendKeys("08-02-1990");
```

but when i am try to click with this same element, the date picker popup will open.
any idea?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - what if you would send keys to the "datepicker" element: `element(by.css("ng-datepicker")).sendKeys("08-02-1990");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the input set readonly="readonly", so you can't input any words by sendKeys.

**Option 1)** execute javascript to set the value of input:

```
var inputEle = element(by.css(".ngx-datepicker-container input"));
var inputValue = '08-02-1990';
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', 
                      inputEle.getWebElement(), 
                      inputValue);
// Click on the input box of Date to make application can detect the changes
// on input
inputEle.click(); // open date picker pop-up <br>
inputEle.click(); // close date picker pop-up <br>
```

**Option 2)** execute javascript to change the Angular model
**Precondition:** 
   1. Your application is Angularjs App 
   2. You know the model name to store input value(please consult with developer if don't know)

I will use an example on https://angularjs.org/ to illustrate:

[image]

```
var modelEle = element(by.xxx) //elemnt binded the model name; 
// please find out which element binded the model name to store the date input by user
var modelName = '';

var modelValue = '08-02-1990';

var script = 'angular.element(arguments[0]).scope()' + 
             '.$apply(function(scope){scope[arguments[1]] = arguments[2]})';

browser.executeScript(script, 
                      modelEle.getWebElement(),
                      modelName,
                      modelValue);
```

Comment: Great Thanks for the reply. Actually our DOB section is on-hold.Now only it started working.So by using above code i am able to set the date into the text box(able to view in UI while running) .But on submission, the applications tells that fields are empty. It is not taking the given value.Is there any method to overcome this?

Comment: Above javascript set the value in background not make angular model change.  If the input still set to readonly,  you have to consult  your developer  how to make the angular model change after execut above code.

Comment: according to developers code, on submitting, value from input filed is not taken into account.Instead seperate control(ng-datepicker) is given for calendar and the date value(on submission) is obtained only on clicking a date from the calendar.So in this case how can i write protractor automated code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add one more code to click on the input box after above script, Seem updated code above

Comment: while running the above code, it setting the date value into the input box and opens the Calendar popup on clicking and the date value which we set is not clearing after the click.

Comment: Yes, I expect the date value not cleared after click. So did the submit obtain the date value?

Comment: Update another option in my answer, but need developer assistance